# support of a measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions

How we define support of a measurable function? Can we say that if $f$ is a measurable function with support $E$ then $E\cup F$ is also $supp(f)$, where $m(F)=0$ and $f=0$ on $F.$

Comment: [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) gives, in particular, the definition of a set-theoretic support.  Are you trying to avoid bizarre supports that may result from having or losing "scraps" that are set of measure zero?

Comment: If you want to talk about **the** support of $f$ you can define it as $\{x:f (x) \neq 0\}$. To bring the measure into consideration you can say $f$ is supported by $S$ if $\mu f^{-1}(S^{c})=0$ but you cannot associate a single set called the support of $f$.

Comment: Could you recommend any text book for the definition you mentioned above? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: As far as I know there is  no book which talks about supports of discontinuous functions. The concept is vague and not helpful. For a continuous function on a topological space the support is defined as the closure of $\{x:f (x)\neq 0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

If I am guessing correctly, you would like to avoid unpleasant situations (e.g., non-uniqueness) with sets of measure zero.  So, how about this little construct for the case when $f$ is defined (and real-valued) on a measure space $(X, {\cal B}, \mu)$, where $X$ is a topological space and ${\cal B}$ the Borel algebra.  Assume, furthermore, $f \geq 0$ a.e..

Define the support of a continuous non-negative function $\phi : X \rightarrow [0, +\infty[$, as usual, as the closure of the set $\phi \neq 0$.

We will say that a continuous function $\phi : X \rightarrow [0, +\infty[$ *majorizes $f$* if $\phi \geq f$ a.e..

We can now define the support of $f$ as the intersection of the supports of all the continuous $\phi : X \rightarrow [0, +\infty[$ that majorize $f$.

One resulting property is: since the supports of all these majorizing functions are closed, their intersection is also closed.

If $f$ is not non-negative a.e., then deal separately with its positive and negative parts, the way I described above.

Comment: It seems logical. Thanks for comment. @avs